# SQL Server Join and Sum Tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 2 tables, table A:

**CategoryId | Qty**

```
1 | 10
2 | 15
```

Table B:

**SaleId | CategoryId | QtyReserved**

```
1 | 1 | 2
2 | 1 | 1
3 | 2 | 5
```

I want to display result like this (joining both tables):

**CategoryId | Qty | QtyReserved**

```
1 | 10 | 3 ---> sum records (column QtyReserved) from table B
2 | 15 | 5
```

How can I possibly achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: hint... SUM ... GROUP BY...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `SUM` and `GROYP BY`

```
SELECT  C.CategoryId,C.Qty,SUM(S.QtyReserved) AS QtyReserved
FROM    tableA AS C
INNER JOIN tableB AS S ON C.CategoryId = S.CategoryId
GROUP BY C.CategoryId,C.Qty
```